# Can F1 score be equal to zero?

Tags: classification, metric, confusion-matrix, scoring-rules, f1

As it is mentioned in [F1 score Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) that 'F1 score reaches its best value at 1 (perfect precision and recall) and **worst at 0**'.

What is the worst condition that was mentioned?

Comment: also posted (with some more detail) at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/72074/55122

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128431/3552975) the F measure can be written as:

$F_{\beta}=\frac{(\beta^2 +1)PR}{R+\beta^2P}$

Then if $P$ or $R$ is zero the $F_{\beta}$ would be zero, and for the $F_1$ in your case suppose that the true labels for a binary classification problem are 1, 1, 0, 0 but your predictions are 0, 0, 1, 1 both the recall and precision are 0 so the $F_1$ is also 0.

Comment: That would cause division by 0.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy If we define $\frac{0}{0}$ as 0 that would be fine. Am I wrong?

Comment: "If we define $\frac00$ as 0..." [Please don't do that.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/556957/493872)

Comment: @BenReiniger Get it. It is then an undefined problem.